# How to convert latitude,longitude to x,y coordinates and draw path on android device using canvas?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I want to draw path of user, according to his movement on the android device using canvas. First of all I get the user current location and then convert those latitude , longitude to x,y coordinates. Then I draw circle at that x,y coordinate consider it as point A.

After every 30 seconds I get the location update. Now suppose if user moved to B location after 30 seconds I want to draw path between those two points A and B. Actually I am getting difference between A point x,y co-ordinates and B point x,y co-ordinates is really small. That's why canvas is not able to draw path between those two point. I don't know the formula I am using to convert latitude,longitude to x,y coordinate is right or wrong ? . Please check. And if it's right then what is the problem. This is my code sample:

```
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                500, // Width
                500, // Height
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 // Config
        );

        canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.LTGRAY);
         c_height = canvas.getHeight();
         c_width = canvas.getWidth();

         paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(18);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);

         paint_circle = new Paint();
        paint_circle.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint_circle.setStrokeWidth(5);
        paint_circle.setColor(Color.RED);


       float dpi = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

        textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

        mImageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        mScaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(this, new ScaleListener());

      buildGoogleApiClient();


    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.i("ERRORR","ERRRRR ="+e.getMessage());
    }
}


protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

    mLocationProvider = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi;

    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(30000);
    //mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(950);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    checkGps();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    RequestLocationUpdates();

    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    try {
        if (flag == 0) {
            Log.i("XCXCX 1", "RGRGRG we");
            first_lat = location.getLatitude();
            first_long = location.getLongitude();
            old_lat = location.getLatitude();
            old_long = location.getLongitude();
            start_altitude = location.getAltitude();
  //            first_x= (float) (340 + ((first_long*340)/180));
  //            first_y= (float) (240 - ((first_lat*240)/180));

  //                first_x = (float) (100 + ((first_long * 100) / 180));
  //                first_y = (float) (100 - ((first_lat * 100) / 180));

            first_x=  (int) ((c_width/360.0) * (180 + first_x));
            first_y =  (int) ((c_height/180.0) * (90 - first_y));

            canvas.drawCircle(first_x, first_y, 5, paint_circle);
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
   //            first_x = (float) (6371 * Math.cos(first_lat) * 
     Math.cos(first_long));
     //            first_y = (float) (6371 * Math.cos(first_lat) * 
       Math.sin(first_long));
             flag = 1;
          } else {
          }

        if (second_flag == 1) {
            Log.i("XCXCX 2", "RGRGRG we");
            second_lat = location.getLatitude();
            second_long = location.getLongitude();
            end_altitude = location.getAltitude();
   //                second_x = (float) (100 + ((second_long * 100) / 180));
   //                second_y = (float) (100 - ((second_lat * 100) / 180));

            second_x=  (int) ((c_width/360.0) * (180 + second_long));
            second_y =  (int) ((c_height/180.0) * (90 - second_lat));
    //second_x = first_x+second_x;
   //second_y = first_y+second_y;
  //            second_x= (float) (340 + ((second_long*340)/180));
  //            second_y= (float) (240 - ((second_lat*240)/180));
 //            second_x = (float) (6371 * Math.cos(second_lat) * 
   Math.cos(second_long));
  //            second_y = (float) (6371 * Math.cos(second_lat) * 
    Math.sin(second_long));

            Location loc1 = new Location("");

   //                loc1.setLatitude(old_lat);
   //                loc1.setLongitude(old_long);

            loc1.setLatitude(first_lat);
            loc1.setLongitude(first_long);

            Location loc2 = new Location("");
            loc2.setLatitude(second_lat);
            loc2.setLongitude(second_long);
            distanceInMeters = loc1.distanceTo(loc2);

            total_distance = total_distance + distanceInMeters;


            drawline();
            first_lat = second_lat;
            first_long = second_long;
 //                first_x = (float) (100 + ((first_long * 100) / 180));
 //                first_y = (float) (100 - ((first_lat * 100) / 180));

            first_x=  (int) ((c_width/360.0) * (180 + first_long));
            first_y =  (int) ((c_height/180.0) * (90 - first_lat));


   //            first_x= (float) (340 + ((first_long*340)/180));
//            first_y= (float) (240 - ((first_lat*240)/180));
//            first_x = (float) (6371 * Math.cos(first_lat) * 
    Math.cos(first_long));
     //            first_y = (float) (6371 * Math.cos(first_lat) * 
     Math.sin(first_long));
     //second_flag = 1;
         } else {

        }
        second_flag = 1;
        int x = (int) first_x;
        int y = (int) first_y;
        ar.add("Latitude: " + first_lat + " longitude: " + first_long + "\n 
x : " + x + " y : " + y + " Distance  = " + total_distance + " \n");
       // textView.setText(ar.toString());

        Log.d("Background Location ", "::::***********Latitude: " + 
   location.getLatitude() + " Longitude: " + location.getLongitude());
    }catch (Exception e){

       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Error="+e.getMessage(),
       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e("ERRROR","ERRRORR ="+e.getMessage());
    }
}
private void RequestLocationUpdates() {


  LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, 
  mLocationRequest, this); //getting error here..for casting..!

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection suspended");
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

}


@Override
public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

public void drawline(){

    Path p = new Path();

 float radius = (float) 5;

 canvas.drawCircle(second_x, second_y, radius, paint_circle);


    p.moveTo(first_x, first_y);
    p.lineTo(second_x, second_y);

canvas.drawPath(p, paint);


    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


}
```

Comment: see http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/projection/SphericalMercatorProjection.html

Comment: Can I achieve this without using SphericalMercatorProjection and  Is it possible to achieve this with my current logic.

Comment: hmmm, hard to say...

Comment: If I use SphericalMercatorProjection and after getting x,y co-ordinate do I need to convert those coordinates into pixel coordinates for different Android devices.

Comment: you have to scale it

Comment: Can you please show me how to do that?